# Operator error in template

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, compiler-errors

I am trying to create a "value" template class, where additional properties can be assign to it easily.
Properties are stored in `std::map<std::string, std::string>`, and `operator[]` has been overloaded to provide quick access to them.

```
#if ! defined __VALUE_H__
#define __VALUE_H__

#include <string>
#include <map>
namespace Algorithm
{
    template<typename TValueType> 
    class CValue
    {
        public:
            CValue(const TValueType& Value) : 
            m_Value(Value)
            {
            }

            ~CValue()
            {
            }

            CValue(const CValue& Source) :
            m_Value(Source.m_Value),
            m_mssProperties(Source.m_mssProperties)
            {
            }

            CValue& operator=(const CValue& Source) 
            {
                if (this != &Source)
                {
                    m_Value = Source.m_Value;
                    m_mssProperties = Source.m_mssProperties;
                }
                return *this;
            }

            CValue& operator=(const TValueType& Source)
            {
                m_Value = Source;
                return *this;
            }

            std::string& operator[](const std::string& sPropertyName)
            {
                return m_mssProperties[sPropertyName];
            }

            std::string operator[](const std::string& sPropertyName) const
            {
                std::map<std::string, std::string>::const_iterator iter;
                iter = m_mssProperties.find(sPropertyName);
                return ((iter!=m_mssProperties.end()) ? iter->second : "");
            }

            operator TValueType () const
            {
                return m_Value;
            }

        private:
            TValueType m_Value;
            std::map<std::string, std::string> m_mssProperties;
    };
};

#endif //__VALUE_H__
```

Why does when I invoke operator[] with string laterals, MSVC2008 complains on overloads ambiguity.

```
#include <string>
#include "Value.h"

int main()
{
    std::string valName = "XX";
    std::string valProp = "YY";
    Algorithm::CValue<int>  obj(valName, 2);
    obj[valProp] = "ZZ";
    obj["AA"] = "BB";       // compiler error
    return 0;
}
```

Compiler error:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: TemplateHell, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Compiling...
1>TemplateHell.cpp
1>c:\documents and settings\yeen-fei.lim\my documents\visual studio 2008\projects\templatehell\templatehell.cpp(13) : error C2666: 'Algorithm::CValue<TValueType>::operator []' : 3 overloads have similar conversions
1>        with
1>        [
1>            TValueType=int
1>        ]
1>        c:\documents and settings\yeen-fei.lim\my documents\visual studio 2008\projects\templatehell\value.h(146): could be 'std::string Algorithm::CValue<TValueType>::operator [](const std::string &) const'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            TValueType=int
1>        ]
1>        c:\documents and settings\yeen-fei.lim\my documents\visual studio 2008\projects\templatehell\value.h(134): or       'std::string &Algorithm::CValue<TValueType>::operator [](const std::string &)'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            TValueType=int
1>        ]
1>        or       'built-in C++ operator[(int, const char [3])'
1>        while trying to match the argument list '(Algorithm::CValue<TValueType>, const char [3])'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            TValueType=int
1>        ]
1>Build log was saved at "file://c:\Documents and Settings\yeen-fei.lim\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\TemplateHell\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
1>TemplateHell - 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

**Edit:**

When i remove implicit conversion-operator from the code, it will compile without error. But it makes no sense for me because it is never used so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`obj["AA"]`... have you seen a similar construct before? There is an old C obfuscation trick where you take the array and the index and reverse them in the expression as `a[b]` is the same as `*(a + b)` which is the same as `b[a]`. In the cast overload in this case, you are returning a integer. The other element of the call is a character array. This confuses the compiler as it doesn't know if this is you trying to get element `obj` of `"AA"`, or if you want the overloaded operator. You can see this in the output of the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class Val {
    T const ret;
public:
    Val(T r) : ret(r) {}

    operator T () const {
        return ret;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Val<int> v(3);
    cout << v["abcd"] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

> d

Consider the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class Val {
    T const ret;
public:
    Val(T r) : ret(r) {}

    operator T () const {
        return ret;
    }
    string operator[](string const &) const {
        return string("Hi!");
    }
};

int main()
{
    Val<int> v(3);
    cout << v["Hello!"] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This gives a similar error. Change `Val<int>` to `Val<double>` and the problem magically goes away (you can't index an array with a double; no confusion).

The solution in this case is to create another overload: `string operator[](char const *) const`. This gets rid of the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

```
obj["AA"] = "BB";
```

"AA" is of type char* and not std::string.

Comment: it might make sense if the error occurred at operator[] which taken parameter of std::string reference. I still can't relate given answer to the implicit conversion-operator.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does when I invoke operator[] with
>   string laterals, MSVC2008 complains on
>   overloads ambiguity.

Because it is ambiguous. You need to change the signature of the function/operator. Make the operators look like this:

```
std::string& operator[](const std::string& sPropertyName);
std::string const& operator[](const std::string& sPropertyName) const;
```

Instead of returning `""` when the key is missing in the map, return a reference to some empty `const std::string` instance.